# Creating a processing queue in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using a Tornado web server to queue up items that need to be processed outside of the request/response cycle.

In my simplified example below, every time a request comes in, I add a new string to a list called `queued_items`. I want to create something that will watch that list and process the items as they show up in it.

(In my real code, the items are processed and sent over a TCP socket which may or may not be connected when the web request arrives. I want the web server to keep queuing up items regardless of the socket connection)

I'm trying to keep this code simple and not use external queues/programs like Redis or Beanstalk. It's not going to have very high volume.

What's a good way using Tornado idioms to watch the `client.queued_items` list for new items and process them as they arrive?

```
import time

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
import tornado.web

class Client():

    def __init__(self):
        self.queued_items = []

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def watch_queue(self):
        # I have no idea what I'm doing
        items = yield client.queued_items
        # go_do_some_thing_with_items(items)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        client.queued_items.append("%f" % time.time())
        self.write("Queued a new item")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = Client()

    # Watch the queue for when new items show up
    client.watch_queue()

    # Create the web server 
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', IndexHandler),
    ], debug=True)

    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a library called [`toro`](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which provides synchronization primitives for `tornado`. **[Update: As of tornado 4.2, `toro` has been merged into `tornado`.]**

Sounds like you could just use a `toro.Queue` (or `tornado.queues.Queue` in `tornado` 4.2+) to handle this:

```
import time

import toro
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
import tornado.web

class Client():

    def __init__(self):
        self.queued_items = toro.Queue()

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def watch_queue(self):
        while True:
            items = yield self.queued_items.get()
            # go_do_something_with_items(items)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        yield client.queued_items.put("%f" % time.time())
        self.write("Queued a new item")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = Client()

    # Watch the queue for when new items show up
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(client.watch_queue)

    # Create the web server 
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', IndexHandler),
    ], debug=True)

    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

There are a few tweaks required, aside from switching the data structure from a list to a `toro.Queue`:

1. We need to schedule `watch_queue` to run inside the IOLoop using `add_callback`, rather than trying to call it directly outside of an IOLoop context.
2. `IndexHandler.get` needs to be converted to a coroutine, because `toro.Queue.put` is a coroutine.

I also added a `while True` loop to `watch_queue`, so that it will run forever, rather than just processing one item and then exiting.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for showing me how to implement it.

Comment: Dano - How can I stop watching the queue? When my connection goes bad, I'll need to temporarily stop processing the items in the queue but not lose them.

Comment: toro has been merged into tornado and is now deprecated. For tornado >= 4.2 you can use `tornado.queues.Queue`

Comment: @MattiJohn Thanks, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am using this code and added a sleep function at `go_do_something_with_items(items)`. Now, if I try to call the api in quick succession the api is blocked and the program waits until the previous request is finished. How can I have concurrent access?

Comment: @ShishirPandey you can't use `time.sleep`; it blocks the event loop. There are other questions on SO that cover how you can sleep via tornado without blocking the event loop. (I'm on mobile right now, so I can't easily search for them right now. )

Comment: `instance()` is deprecated alias for `IOLoop.current()` since tornado 5.0